# Adobe Reader Fill and Sign - Same word for many fields?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I am digitally filling out an employment application for a company. However, when I get to fill in certain fields, Reader automatically takes what's in that field and puts it for several other fields on the same form. So if I put "Joe" for the name field, it would put "Joe" for the name field plus several other unrelated fields such as Address and Telephone.

Is this something that's client-sided, like a local program feature, or was it an error on the company's part when building the PDF? I can't find an option to disable it and Google wasn't much help. I'd much rather digitally fill it out that print it, but I will print it if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The creator of the PDF probably used the same name for different form fields. This results in the mentioned behaviour when filling out the form.

So to answer your question: It's not a client side problem.